# Why does Diesel fail to migrate a PostgresSQL database when the columns specify a length?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

When I generate migrations with `diesel migration generate customers`, if the `up.sql` file in the migrations folder contains no brackets for column length:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  identity VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  hometown VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  age INT NOT NULL
)
```

When I run `diesel migration run --database-url=postgres://<info>`, it successfully migrates the database.

Why would the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  identity VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  hometown VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  age INT(11) NOT NULL
)
```

raise the error:

```
Failed with: syntax error at or near "("
```

My SQL isn't amazing, hence why I went straight for an ORM, but I believe the SQL queries are both perfectly valid, I'm at a loss of where to look to debug.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use the diesel client to use diesel. Those are different things.

Comment: If what you meant is that Diesel is the core ORM for interacting with the database, and the cli provides a means to perform actions such as generating migration schemas and applying them to the database, I got that already. If not, could you elaborate?

Comment: Nope, I just wanted to make that clear.

Comment: "I beleive the SQL queries are both perfectly valid" -> No. It [doesn't look like PostgreSQL supports `int(n)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-numeric.html).

Comment: Thanks, I am now aware that mysql and postgres sql statements differ.